# Is there way to use @Scheduled together with Duration string like 15s and 5m?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

I have following annotation in my code

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${app.delay}")
```

At this case I have to have properties like this

```
app.delay=10000 #10 sec
```

Propery file looks unreadable because I have calculate value to miliseconds.

Is there way to pass value like 5m or 30s there ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do it directly. However, Spring boot configuration properties do [support automatic conversion](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-conversion-duration) of parameters like `15s` and `5m` to `Duration`.

This means you could create a `@ConfigurationProperties` class like this:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties("app")
public class AppProperties {
    private Duration delay;

    // Setter + Getter
}
```

Additionally, since you can use [bean references with Spring's Expression Language](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-bean-references) within the `@Scheduled` annotation, you can do something like this:

```java
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "#{@'app-com.xyz.my.pkg.AppProperties'.delay}")
public void schedule() {
    log.info("Scheduled");
}
```

> **Note**: When you use `@EnableConfigurationProperties` or `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan`, the configurationproperties beans are registered with the name `<prefix>-<fully qualified classname>`. So in the example above, I'm assuming that the `AppProperties` class is located in a package called `com.xyz.my.pkg`.
>
> If you don't like this, you can also use the `@Component("beanName")` annotation on top of the `AppProperties` class to give it a different bean name.

---

Alternatively, you can programmatically add a task to the `TaskScheduler`. The benefit of that is that you have more compile-time safety.

```java
@Bean
public ScheduledFuture<?> schedule(TaskScheduler scheduler, AppProperties properties) {
    return scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> log.info("Scheduled"), properties.getDelay());
}
```

Comment: Could you please check that you use correct symbols here: **@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "#{@appProperties.getDelay().toMillis()}")**

Comment: @gstackoverflow Can you explain what you mean? Is it not working for you? Is something not clear?

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Could you specify what is bean names, what is property key ?

Comment: Parameter 0 of constructor in foo.bar.Bean required a bean named 'appProperties' that could not be found.

Comment: I solved the issue. It was because I used ConfigurationProperties("app") +EnableConfigurationProperties. ConfigurationProperties + Component is a working combination

Comment: @gstackoverflow Yeah, `@EnableConfigurationProperties` uses a different bean naming convention, and thus won't work. I googled a bit around and found [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19390) which is very similar to yours. They suggest using `@Component` or using the second solution I provided.

Comment: `toMillis()` is actually not even needed. `ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` is perfectly happy to accept your duration instead.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're using a recent enough version of Spring, you can use any String that can be parsed to a `java.time.Duration`. In your case:

```
PT10S
```

Comment: yes, it works. But unfortunately **10s** doesn't work although spring able to parse **10s** to Duration

Answer (score 4):

I'm using this code and it works fine:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "PT10S")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just adjust your annotation to use a SpEL multiplication.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "#{${app.delay} * 1000}")
```

Comment: That wouldn't work for me. Got "Incompatible types, found String required Long"... but it works for fixedDelayString

Answer (score 2):

I understand this is a fairly old question but maybe it's worth to provide an updated (as of 2023) answer.

There are actually a couple of ways to do this.

I will assume the property is defined as a "natural" time string, i.e. `app.delay=20s` instead of `app.delay=PT20S`, but both cases would work.

### Plain Properties

If the property `app.delay` is *not* part of of `@ConfigurationProperties`, you can use the following expression:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "#{T(org.springframework.boot.convert.ApplicationConversionService).getSharedInstance().convert('${app.delay}', T(java.time.Duration)).toMillis()}")
```

### Configuration Properties

If you defined the property `app.delay` as part of "normal" (i.e. not a `@Component`) `@ConfigurationProperties`, like so:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("app")
public class AppProperties {
    private Duration delay;
    // Getters + Setters
}
```

Then, assuming this class is in package `com.package`, you can use

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "#{@'app-com.package.AppProperties'.getDelay().toMillis()}")
```

Because this is how naming of the Configuration Properties beans works in Spring Boot (see [reference doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.enabling-annotated-types)).

### Configuration Properties (as `@Component`)

(which is the original answer by [@g00glen00b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1915448/g00glen00b))
If you defined the property `app.delay` as part of `@ConfigurationProperties`, which are also a `@Component` like so:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("app")
public class AppProperties {
    private Duration delay;
    // Getters + Setters
}
```

Then you can refer to the bean name as follows

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "#{@appProperties.getDelay().toMillis()}")
```