# Using fixedDelayString in spring-boot @Scheduled without putting the configuration property directly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

Here's my problem. I'm using `@Scheduled` on top of some methods to do some regular tasks in my spring-boot application.

For configuring the schedule I'm using the `fixedDelayString` & `initialDelayString` arguments to `@Scheduled` as follows:

```
@Scheduled(
      initialDelayString = "${my.wanted.delayInSeconds}",
      fixedDelayString = "${my.wanted.delayInSeconds}"
  )
```

Which works like it should.

The problem I have now is this, in the properties file for the application I **have to** put the configuration property as:

```
my.wanted.delayInSeconds=10
```

If I use any of the other supported cases for spring properties, like kebab-case for example:

```
my.wanted.delay-in-seconds=10
```

The application fails to boot up with an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'myMethod': Could not resolve placeholder 'my.wanted.delayInseconds' in value "${my.wanted.delayInSeconds}"
```

Which makes sense since that value is not defined & spring doesn't seem to be doing the conversions for `fixedDelayString` & `initialDelayString` placeholders.

The problem is that this seems really easy to break. I'm reading that same property from a usual `@ConfigurationProperties` class as well. So IntelliJ keeps suggesting me to use the kebab-case version in the property files i.e. `my.wanted.delay-in-seconds`. And I agree - it's easier to read there. But if I do that, the app will not boot up.

So my question is: Is there any way to

- Either, have spring do the usual conversions so that the kebab-case will also work?
- Or, provide the delay strings from a configuration property class instead of using the property directly?

Thanks!

Comment: How about the answer provided here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59786883/is-there-way-to-use-scheduled-together-with-duration-string-like-15s-and-5m ?

Comment: It was as simple as that! Thanks @wjans . If you don't mind making a proper answer out of that, I won't mind accepting it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @wjans comment above, the right way to achieve what I wanted was to use SEL to get bean property from my properties bean & use that in the `@Scheduled` argument.

Like so:

```java
@Scheduled(
      initialDelayString = "#{@myProps.getSchedulingDelayMillis()}",
      fixedDelayString = "#{@myProps.getSchedulingDelayMillis()}"
  )
```

This will pull the delay strings from the properties class, so you can bind whatever you need to that property & use it.